# Number of bosonic states in a $n$ particle system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Lets assume we have a system of three particles in which three energy-levels labeled by $$E_1, E_2, E_3$$ are occupied. We want to write down all states that are symmetric (bosonic). One symmetric state is easily found by using a [permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent), but how do I know that it is the only one? How many bosonic states are there if there are $n$ particles involved?

Comment: Fill n(bosons number) identical balls into N(num. of energy levels) buckets, how many ways?

Comment: ah, ok I see, that would be $$\binom{N+n-1}{N}$$. But I think each of those states could be represented by a permanent, couldn't they? And they are therefore linear combinations of product states. I was wondering in terms of this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11419/example-of-a-wavefunction-that-cannot-be-represented-by-a-single-slater-determin How do I count for states (wavefunctions) that aren't product states?